# Set up wiremock(standalone) running as an azure app service

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-appservice

I have developed a springboot application that internally starts the wiremock on port say 8082 and I have server.port = 8085 in application.properties file.

Testing it locally, I'm able to hit both springboot endpoint and the wiremock stubs pointing to 2 different 8085 and 8082 ports respectively. But in Azure, when I deploy it as an app service, Im not able to access wiremock since it is running on a different port.
And as I have read, we cannot configure multiple inbound ports for an app service. Its only 80 and 443.

Is there any other workaround for running wiremock as an Azure app service

I tried pointing wiremock to 80 and 443 port but it gave an Address already in use error.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other workaround for running wiremock as an Azure app service.

As we know that the inbound traffic supports only 80 and 443 ports in Azure app service, To access both spring boot endpoint and wiremock(standalone) from the same port there was the way that is **reverse proxy**.

- For that, first we need to set up some settings check the below.
  [image]
- Add the application settings, this is required for the reverse proxy to work properly.
  [image]
- Specify the IP address and port of Wiremock server to the VNet and hybrid connections also.
  [image]
- Add inbound security rule set the protocol **TCP**
  and ranges to 8085.
  Below added a sample template code for better understanding.

```
    private static final String WIREMOCK_HOST = "wiremock-app-service.azurewebsites.net";
    private static final int WIREMOCK_PORT = 80;

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public HelloWorldController(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
        String url = "http://" + WIREMOCK_HOST + ":" + WIREMOCK_PORT + "/hello";
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

In second case we can use Azure functions by creating HTTP-triggered Azure Function and use a library like Apache HttpComponents or OkHttp to make requests to the Spring Boot application. that makes the port active with wiremock is running with the same library to forward requests to the application on port 8085.